# How to give ul nav tabs width space but still float left

Tags: html, css

I have an unordered list used for navigation tabs. I want them to have space between them but I also want the beginning of the list to line up with the rest of the text to the left.

I know this is simple but I can't figure it out.

http://jsfiddle.net/29g9S/3/

```
<body>


<div class="page-box">
    <p>I am trying to get the ul's li's to line up with the "My Blog" text and still flow with the document</p>


<h1>My Blog</h1>

    <ul>                
        <li>test</li>
        <li>test</li>
        <li>test</li>
        </ul>



</div>


</body>
```

**CSS**

```
.page-box{
    position:relative;
    left:50px;
}

ul{

    position:relative;
    left:0px;
}

ul>li{
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    margin-left:100px;
    list-style-type:none;
}
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/29g9S/7/ Check this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key is killing the `margin` / `padding` on the `ul`:

```
.page-box{
    position:relative;
    left:50px;
}

ul{
    position:relative;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

ul>li{
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
    margin:0 100px 0 0;
    list-style-type:none;
}
```

[Here is an updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/29g9S/6/). Notice the use of `display:inline-block;` instead of `float:left;`. Floats are a one way ticket to old webville! Embrace the wonder that is `display:inline-block`! :D

Answer (score 0):

If i understood correctly css can be modified as follows,

http://jsfiddle.net/fTdHH/

```
ul{

    position:relative;
    left:0px;
    padding:0px;
}

ul>li{
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    /* margin-left:100px; */
    margin-right:100px;
    list-style-type:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set

```
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
ul>li {
  // no margin-left
  margin-right: 100px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/beautifulcoder/29g9S/8/

Answer (score 0):

PlantTheldea is right about the margin/padding on the `ul`.  If you want to keep the list items floated with margin-left, just remove the margin-left from the first list-item by using `li:first-child`:

```
.page-box {
    position:relative;
    left:50px;
}
ul {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    position:relative;
    left:0px;
}
ul>li {
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    margin-left:100px;
    list-style-type:none;
}
ul>li:first-child {
    margin-left:0;
}
```

Also, is there are reason you're using position:relative on everything rather than just adding margin or padding to `.page-box`?